# Springboot - multiple property files per profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

Looking for best approach in configuring multiple Profile specific property files in Springboot application.  Below is an example:

-resources
      -- application.properties
             -- dev
                        -- application-dev.properties
                        -- ldap-dev.properties
                        -- quartz-dev.properties
                        -- etc-dev.properties
           -- test 
                        -- application-test.properties
                        -- ldap-test.properties
                        -- quartz-test.properties
                        -- etc-test.properties
            -- prod
                        -- application-prod.properties
                        -- ldap-prod.properties
                        -- quartz-prod.properties
                        -- etc-prod.properties

The application.properties and application-profile.properties files are loading okay.  I'm looking for a recommended approach in loading the other profile specific property files.  I'm not sure if there is a way to load all property files from a folder based on a profile?

Answer (score 6):

You have quite a lot of flexibility with the built in configuration listener. E.g. You could set `spring.config.name=application,ldap,quartz,etc` and `spring.config.location=classpath:/,classpath:/dev,classpath:/prod,classpath:/test`. Or the equivalent env vars. The links in Selim's answer document the basic behaviour and config options.

Answer (score 4):

As of Spring boot 2.0.4, this feature comes out of the box as long as you specify your config file in `spring.config.name` environment variable, e.g `spring.config.name=application,ldap,quartz`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure is there any better way to that or is my suggestion really work but you can try this:

Add `@PropertySource` Annotation right before your configuration class

```
@PropertySource("classpath:ldap-${spring.profiles.active}.properties", "classpath:quartz-${spring.profiles.active}.properties", "classpath:etc-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
```

To understand better how Spring load configurations from different sources and profiles see [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`@PropertySources` can be used to load multiple properties files with profile as
    `ldap-${spring.profiles.active}.properties`

But if you are using YAML, `@PropertySource` will not work. You have to use `@ConfigurationProperty` to load YML files other than application.yml